# Failure of readProcess "grep" in Haskell because of a strange file

Tags: linux, haskell, encoding

I have a file `MAIL.txt` containing strange characters (this file comes from Windows and I am on Linux). It contains the character string `rec`. When I run `grep "rec" MAIL.txt` in a terminal, I get the expected output.

However this command fails in Haskell:

```
Prelude System.Process> r <- readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["rec", "MAIL.txt"] ""
*** Exception: fd:13: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

What is the explanation and is there a way to avoid that (without modifying the strange file)?

Here is the output of `grep` where you can see the strange characters:

[image]

In fact these should be accented letters.

I cannot read the file with `readFile`:

```
> r <- readFile "MAIL.txt"
> r
"Bonjour,\r\n\r\n Quelques remarques sur cette fiche :\r\n\r\n- *** Exception: MAIL.txt: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

Maybe there's a way to detect the problem with [Data.Binary](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.4.1/docs/Data-Binary.html)?

## Solution

To detail @ErikR's answer:

```
import System.Process.ByteString (readProcessWithExitCode)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString, empty)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import System.Exit (ExitCode)
(err, stdout, stderr) <- readProcessWithExitCode "grep" ["rec", "MAIL.txt"] empty
B.putStrLn stdout
```

Comment: Do you know the exact encoding of the file?

Comment: Probably the file is latin-1 encoded, when Haskell (as most applications in linux nowadays) tries to decode it as utf8.

Comment: I just tried readFile on a latin-1 file with accents, Haskell shows character codes like \218, but does not crash. You should try to reduce your file to a small region that has the problem and post it.

Comment: Could you post an excerpt from your file that causes this error? It would be much easier to help you if we could reproduce the problem on our own machines.

Comment: @chi : readFile returns a String, not a Text. It doesn't know UTF8.

Comment: @V.Semeria A String is a list of unicode code points, so decoding is performed. The actual encoding is set via `hSetEncoding` on a handle (e.g. stdin) in text mode.

Comment: My mistake. I thought Char and Word8 were the same type.

Comment: @danidiaz `file -i MAIL.txt` returns `iso-8859-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readProcessWithExitCode` or `readCreateProcessWithExitCode` from the [process-extras](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-extras-0.4.1.4/docs/System-Process-ByteString.html) package. They return ByteStrings:

```
readProcessWithExitCode :: FilePath -> [String] -> ByteString
       -> IO (ExitCode, ByteString, ByteString)
```

Other versions exists for return lazy Bytestrings and Text.

Edit: Updated links since process-listlike is deprecated in favor of process-extras.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try later. This is not important, I'm just playing with Haskell :)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Keep in mind that a ByteString contains bytes, not characters -- if you want to do text processing you might want to decode it to a `Text` before starting the actual processing. For that, you need to specify an encoding, and use some library.

Comment: Works fine! Thank you.